# Creating and combining numerous images in Python - Error: Too many open files:

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, glob

So basically I've got 2 codes:

1. One creates a number of different coloured images with 1 pixel dimensions
2. The other combines all the created images into one

The first one works perfectly but in the second code I get an error: `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'Test 3161.png'`

The thing is I don't necessarily want to create the files. What I really want is the combined image at the end. I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code 1 - Creating images

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

im = Image.new("RGB", (1, 1))
pix = im.load()

j=0

for r in range(65,130):
    for g in range(65,130):
        for b in range(65,130):
            for x in range(1):
                for y in range(1):
                    axis = (r,g,b)
                    pix[x,y] = axis
                print axis
                j+=1
                im.save('Test {}.png'.format(j), "PNG")
```

Code 2: Combining images

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import glob

imgfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    imgfiles.append(file)
print imgfiles

#stitching images together
images = map(Image.open, imgfiles)
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
    new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
    x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('test.png')
```

This is somewhat the final image I'm trying to get but not with as many colours as shown in it:
[image]

The coloured images that are created from code 1 are images that are 1 pixel in width and diameter. For example like this:

[image]

Its harder to see as its one pixel right next to this. It looks like a fullstop but is the 1 pixel image in question.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do overall? It's quite hard to understand - you seem to be making thousands of images you don't want for some reason and then trying to stitch them back together in some unknown way. What will the result look like? And what's an image *"with 1 pixel dimensions"* please?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please let me know if you don't understand

Comment: So you want an image that is 1pixel high and 65*65*65 pixels wide?

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what you expect to produce, but this should be close and a lot faster and easier:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Create array to hold output image
result=np.zeros([1,13*13*13,3],dtype=np.uint8)

j=0
for r in range(65,130,5):
    for g in range(65,130,5):
        for b in range(65,130,5):
            result[0,j]= (r,g,b)
            j+=1

# Convert output array to image and save
im=Image.fromarray(result)
im.save("result.jpg")
```

[image]

Note that the above script is intended to do the job of **both** of your scripts in one go.

Note that I made the result image a bit taller (fatter) so you can see it, in fact it is only 1 pixel high.

Note that I added a step of 5 to make the output image smaller because it otherwise exceeds the size limits - for JPEG at least.

Note that I coarsely guessed the array width (13*13*13) on the basis of (130-65)/5, because I don't really understand your requirements.

Comment: The image I'm trying to produce is a combination of 'pixels with different RGB values' in a horizontal fashion so for example assume each . is a pixel. I'm creating a combination of . like ................ all the way up to 65^3 where each pixel has a different RGB value. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the too-many-open-files error, you can make a little function:

```
def getImageDetails(imgfile):
    im = Image.open(imgfile)
    size = im.size
    im.load() # closes the pointer after it loads the image

    return size[0], size[1], im

widths, heights, images = zip(*(getImageDetails(i) for i in imgfiles))
```

replace these lines with the code above:

```
images = map(Image.open, imgfiles)
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I got another error. `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: I fixed that error, apologies. Assumed that Im.size was a function but it is actually an attribute.